# How to initialize char[] array with Java stream?

Tags: java, arrays, char, initialization

Very silly question, but how can I make such array with spaces between the elements.

For example we can initialize array of String like this:

```
scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
```

And initialize array of integers like this:

```
Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

But how do we initialize array of chars with space in between?

Comment: [`String#toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())?

Comment: Please edit your question and include examples of the input you expect, and the output you would like to get.  At first I thought you just wanted to read a char array, but your second example seems to suggest that you want the parse operation to generate a char array, and it’s not clear whether you want individual characters or something else.

Comment: @VGR okay. My example input is: a b c d  Between them there are spaces. Is it actually possible to initialize such array of chars or not..?

Comment: `string.remove(' ').toCharArray()`?

Comment: @JBNizet Or perhaps `string.replace(" ", "").toCharArray()`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Brain fart. Thanks for the correction :-)